# c# dynamic accessing child as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have the following dynamic object as IEnumerable of type dynamic

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "subList": [
      {"specialId": 42}, 
      {"specialId": 27}
    ]
}, 
 {
    "id": 2,
    "subList": [
      {"specialId": 13}, 
      {"specialId": 14}
    ]
}]
```

I can get the objects into a IEnumerable of Dynamics and can run linq queries like the following

```
listOfDynamics.Where(x => x.id == 2);
```

However what I would like to do is be able to do is match on the subList

```
listOfDynamics.Where(x => ((IEnumerable)x.subList)).Where(y => y.specialId == 42));
```

so in the example above it would return the object with id of 1 but not the id of 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Where` you want to check if the `subList` contains any element with `specialId == 42`:

```
listOfDynamics.Where(x => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)x.subList).Any(y => y.specialId == 42));
```

So [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) is the method you want.

And you need to cast `x.subList` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of only `IEnumerable` (as suggested by @Ivan-Stoev and @Derked in the comments).

Comment: While in general this is a correct answer, the way it is now it does not even compile.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are right, I just copied the original line. Have to admit that I'm not so familiar with dynamics, so I'm not sure how to correctly cast this subList to the correct `IEnumerable<ofWhat>` or if this is even necessary.

Comment: `IEnumerable<dynamic>` should be sufficient:)

Comment: `listOfDynamics.Where(x => ((IEnumerable)x.subList).Cast<dynamic>().Any(y => y.specialId == 42))` worked for me!